# A file program debugged under GDB doesn't see its files

Tags: linux, gdb

I'm trying to gdb a program under Linux. It's a compiler of a language that uses some include files (this language include files, not C/C++ includes) that get properly loaded when running the app normally. When run under gdb, the app complains that it couldn't find these include files. I've checked gdb's internal pwd, and it is exactly the same as when run stand-alone. What could be the problem? How can I fix it?

Note that this compiler doesn't use any environment variables, it gets its includes from current directory, it seems.

Comment: Keep in mind that debugging with gdb can be done without gdb having access to the source code as long as the application contains debugging symbols. It will still be able to tell you the functions and code line which you then can inspect manually in your favorite code editor.

Comment: Can you try running your program with `strace -e trace=file yourprogram` ? strace will do some of the same things that gdb does (such as disabling setuid and setgid), and with the `-e trace=file` option, it will show you file errors (permission denied, does not exist, etc.).

Comment: With strace it runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the source directories path in gdb..

go through the **source path** in gdb document.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#Source-Path

Comment: The files are not source files for debug, but data for the application being run.